# Loop String ArrayList to setText in an EditText Array

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am using contents in one ArrayList(String) to be used to update another ArrayList(EditText). I want to loop through the String array, get its detail and use it to setText for each corresponding EditText in the ArrayList(EditText).

So String at index 0 will be used to edit EditText at index 0 and so on. I was trying to use a double For loop but it ends filing all the EditTexts as "quantity". I understand why, but is there even a way to loop through this to do this? Or I need to find a different method?

```
ArrayList<String> detailArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "category", "name", "brand", "quantity"));
ArrayList<EditText> emptyFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                category, name, brand, quantity));

for(EditText x : emptyFields){
    for(String y : detailArray){
        x.setText(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the lists are the same size you don't need 2 loops. Use a regular for loop then just use the the loop variable in both get and set methods.

Comment: @takendarkk I clearly overcomplicated it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
for(int i = 0; i < emptyFields.size(); i++) {
    emptyFields.get(i).setText(detailArray.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you trust both ArrayLists have same sizes, use this

```
for(EditText x : emptyFields){
    x.setText(detailArray.get(emptyFields.indexOf(x))));
}
```